# Unable to mock node-fetch using fetch-mock

Tags: javascript, node.js, sinon-chai, fetch-mock

I am trying to do unit testing for a simple function which sends a get request, receives a response and then returns a promise object with the success or the failure message. Following is the function:

```
module.exports.hello = async (event, context) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch("https://httpstat.us/429", { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }).then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      if (response.status == 200) {
        return response;
      } else {
        throw Error(response.status + ": " + response.statusText);
      }
    }).then(tokenData => {
      resolve({ status: 200, body: JSON.stringify({ statusText: 'Success' }) });
    }).catch(error => {
      reject(error.message);
    });
  });
};
```

While unit testing, I am using fetch-mock to mock the call to the api and have a custom response. Following is the code:

```
it('hello returns failure message', (done) => {
    fetchMock.get('*',  {
        status: 429,
        statusText: "Too Many Nothings",
        headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' }
     });

    edx.hello(null, null).catch(error => {
        expect(error).to.equal('429: Too Many Requests');
    }).then(() => {
        done();
    }).catch(error => {
        done(error);
    });
});
```

But this code is not mocking the fetch request as when I print the response text it is "Too Many Requests" which is being sent as a response by the API and not "Too Many Nothings" which is being mocked. I am new to NodeJS. Please tell me what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `node-fetch` package, it's not available at the global scope in Node.js. In order to make `fetch-mock` work you either have to assign fetch to `global` object (e.g. by `import "node-fetch";` instead of `import fetch from "node-fetch";`) or make fetch injectable to your tested method.

From http://www.wheresrhys.co.uk/fetch-mock/#usageglobal-non-global:

> **Global or non-global**
>
> fetch can be used by your code globally or locally. It’s important to
> determine which one applies to your codebase as it will impact how you
> use fetch-mock
>
> **Global fetch**
>
> In the following scenarios fetch will be a global
>
> - When using native fetch (or a polyfill) in the browser
> - When node-fetch has been assigned to global in your Node.js process (a pattern sometimes used in isomorphic codebases)
>
> By default fetch-mock assumes fetch is a global so no more setup is
> required once you’ve required fetch-mock. Non-global fetch library
>
> In the following scenarios fetch will not be a global
>
> - Using node-fetch in Node.js without assigning to global
> - Using fetch-ponyfill in the browser
> - Using libraries which use fetch-ponyfill internally
> - Some build setups result in a non-global fetch, though it may not always be obvious that this is the case
>
> The sandbox() method returns a function that can be used as a drop-in
> replacement for fetch. Pass this into your mocking library of choice.
> The function returned by sandbox() has all the methods of fetch-mock
> exposed on it, e.g.
>
> ```
> const fetchMock = require('fetch-mock');
> const myMock = fetchMock.sandbox().mock('/home', 200); // pass myMock in to your application code, instead of fetch, run it, then...
> expect(myMock.called('/home')).to.be.true;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

How is `fetch` imported in your file used by your function?
I've got a really basic (almost) VanillaJs file that was using `import fetch from "cross-fetch";` but that meant `fetchMock` from my test file was being ignored.
Switching to `import "cross-fetch/polyfill";` allowed me to have tests that provided mocked fetch data *and* I could have tests that that accessed real data as well.